# Improve toggle menu Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, uikit, toggle

I need an opinion for my JS code. I'm starting in Jquery and trying do a toggle menu using the UI Jquery for my site. Can remake the code I want improve my skills. Sorry for my english. 
.................................................................

```js
var trigger = $('.pht-lista li');
  var digital = $('#artDigital');
  var tradicional = $('#tradicional');

  
  $('.menuTipos').each(function(){

    trigger.click(function(event) {
      trigger.not(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    digital.click(function(e){
      if(digital.hasClass('active')){
        $('.subArtDigital').toggle('slow/400/fast');
        $('.subTradicional').hide();
      }else{
        $('.subArtDigital').hide();
      }
    });
    tradicional.click(function(e){
      if(tradicional.hasClass('active')){
        $('.subTradicional').toggle('slow/400/fast');
        $('.subArtDigital').hide();
      }else{
        $('.subTradicional').hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.pht-lista li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #625F5F;
  transition: .4s ease; }
  .pht-lista li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff; }
.pht-lista li:hover {
  background-color: #3D3A3A; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.xx.x/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.xx.x/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-modal" id="modalTypeFile">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-blank">
   <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close uk-close-alt"></a>
   <div class="uk-modal-header">
    <div class="uk-width-1-1 titleBar">
     <p>Tipo</p>
    </div>
   </div>
          <div class="uk-grid menuTipos">
           <div class="listaPrincipal uk-width-large-2-10 uk-width-medium-3-10 uk-width-small-hidden">
            <ul class="pht-lista">
             <li class="pht-linkLista" id="artDigital"><a>Art Digital</a></li>
             <li class="pht-linkLista" id="tradicional"><a>Tradicional</a></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
           <div style="display: none" class="subArtDigital uk-width-large-2-10 uk-width-medium-3-10 uk-width-small-hidden">
            Digital
           </div>
           <div style="display: none" class="subTradicional uk-width-large-2-10 uk-width-medium-3-10 uk-width-small-hidden">
            Tradicional
           </div>
          </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

.

Comment: Please post your question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok! Thanks for information!